# Get array of indices of first zero in every row of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of 1650 rows and 1275 columns containing 0s and 255s.
I want to get the index of every first zero in the row and store it in an array.
I used for loop to achieve that. Here is the example code

```
#new_arr is a numpy array and k is an empty array 
for i in range(new_arr.shape[0]):
  if not np.all(new_arr[i,:]) == 255:
   x = np.where(new_arr[i,:]==0)[0][0]
   k.append(x)
  else:
   k.append(-1)
```

It takes around 1.3 seconds for 1650 rows. Is there any other way or function to get the indices array in a much faster way?

Comment: What if there's no zero in a row?

Comment: I need answer for that too! Im sorry I didnt even think abt it.

Comment: So, what answer do you need for such a case?

Comment: Would that be nice if I put -1 if there are no zereos in a row?

Comment: Updated my post on it.

Comment: You appear from nowhere and answer in seconds when I ask a numpy related question. Thanks @Divakar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145559/discussion-between-bharath-shetty-and-divakar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach would be to get mask of matches with `==0` and then get [`argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) along each row, i.e `argmax(axis=1)` that gives us the first matching index for each row -

```
(arr==0).argmax(axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [443]: arr
Out[443]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0]])

In [444]: (arr==0).argmax(axis=1)
Out[444]: array([0, 6, 2, 3])
```

**Catching non-zero rows (*if we can!*)**

To facilitate for rows that won't have any zero, we need to do one more step of work, with some masking -

```
In [445]: arr[2] = 9

In [446]: arr
Out[446]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1],
       [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
       [2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0]])

In [447]: mask = arr==0

In [448]: np.where(mask.any(1), mask.argmax(1), -1)
Out[448]: array([ 0,  6, -1,  3])
```

Comment: By itself, this could give an unexpected answer if a row happens to be all zeroes, though.

Comment: @DSM Guess you meant no zero? :)

Comment: 0.0018 seconds. OMG! For loops suck when it comes to numpy.

Comment: Though when I had no zereos in a row,the resultant array had zeroes in that case.

Comment: @BharathShetty By resultant, you mean output from the proposed solution? Not sure really what's going on there.

Comment: I meant for the first solution you gave before answering non-zero rows. The output had zereos. I dont know why it gave 0th index.

Comment: @BharathShetty Yeah, because there was no zero. That's why we needed the fix as listed in the second section.

Comment: What should I do if I even want the row index in the array??

Comment: @BharathShetty I am assuming you want the row index where we have no zero? Then, do : `np.flatnonzero(~(mask.any(1)))`. Lose the `~` for the rest of cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145564/discussion-between-bharath-shetty-and-divakar).